# How to avoid IP list overriding in existing inbound rule

Tags: batch-file, ip, firewall

How to avoid IP list overriding when adding IPs to an existing inbound rule using the below batch script.

**ipadd.bat:**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (ips.txt) do (
  echo line=%%a
  netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Testrule" dir=in protocol=any new remoteip=%%a
)
```

**ips.txt**

IPs listed with line breaks (each on new line)

Now everytime I add new IPs to the ips.txt, the rule updates with new IP but old IP list is overidden with new set of IPs. Is there a way to update and not lose old list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo OFF
IF NOT EXIST installedips.txt >installedips.txt ECHO @
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
 'findstr /x /v /i /L /g:installedips.txt "ips.txt" '
 ) do (
  echo line=%%a
  >>installedips.txt echo %%a
  netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Testrule" dir=in protocol=any new remoteip=%%a
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should fulfill the requirements.

Keep a log of the installed ips in `installedips.txt` - create that file with a dummy value if it doesn't exist.

Then process each line of the file, `/v` excluding lines that `/x` exactly match `/i` regardless of case `/L` literally `/g:` any line on the `installedips.txt` file.

So the only lines that will be processed are the new lines, and the new value will be appended to the `installedips.txt` file.

(not tested)